# Getting all zip codes with a distance of 50 miles from a specific zip code

Tags: sql, sql-server, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a page where a user can insert their zip code and it will return all zip codes near their code.

Right now I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[zip](
    [zipcode] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [state] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [longitude] [float] NULL,
    [latitude] [float] NULL,        
    [CreateStamp] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [state_name] [varchar](50) NULL,        
)
```

I'm not sure how to do this if you can give me a full instruction it would be great

Outcome would be a user insert their zip code, then the query would return all zip codes within 50 miles of their own zip code.

Comment: how do you calculate the distance?

Comment: I assume your table provides longitude and latitude for a "center" of each ZIP Code and the task is to locate all ZIP Codes within a given distance from a "center" of a given ZIP Code, right?  If this is indeed the case you may want to use this reference: <http://johndyer.name/latitudelongitude-distance-calculation-in-sql-server/>.

Comment: PM 77-1 Yes that is the task and i do have longitude and latitude for each zip code.

Comment: PM i get a 404 error when going to that site

Comment: @Neo - See the link I just added above. SELECT statement itself is trivial but you need to implement the formula that finds distances on a sphere (not plain).

Comment: Yep. I can't use the link either. Not sure why. Here it's is again:[http://johndyer.name/latitudelongitude-distance-calculation-in-sql-server/](http://johndyer.name/latitudelongitude-distance-calculation-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `SQL Server 2008` and later, you can use the [`GEOGRAPHY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) data type.
First, you need to get the `Geography` location of the center, based on its zipcode, then select all the records within the specified distance. To calculate distance, use [`STDistance`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) method.
Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @cZip VARCHAR(5)
SET @cZip = '<center zip code>'
DECLARE @dMin DECIMAL = 50 * 1609.344 -- metres

DECLARE @c GEOGRAPHY
SELECT @c = GEOGRAPHY::Parse('Point(' + CAST(longitude AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(latitude AS VARCHAR) + ')')
FROM zip
WHERE zipcode = @cZip

SELECT * 
FROM zip 
WHERE @c.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Parse('Point(' + CAST(longitude AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(latitude AS VARCHAR) + ')')) <= @dMin
```